# How to use the Tailwind CSS dark mode feature with SCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

I followed the Tailwind documentation to implement dark mode using the "Tailwind dark mode variant". The CSS works when I apply it directly to my components as:

```
<footer className={`${styles.footer} dark:bg-midnight`}>
```

However, when I try to use the same inside the SCSS it doesn't work.

```css
.footer {
  @apply bg-primary-blue-900 dark:bg-midnight px-7 py-10 md:px-16 md:py-8 2xl:px-24 2xl:py-10;
}
```

Is there some other way to use dark mode variant when dealing with SCSS and using `@apply`?

I'm new to Tailwind and I'm not able to find a resource that answers this.

Comment: The syntax seems to be ok, it should work. Maybe something in your config? What version of Tailwind do you use?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka `"tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"` This is what package.json tells.

Comment: It looks like this might be a known issue: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2917 and https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3942 (similar, but V2 in JIT mode).

Answer (score 0):

You're currently toggling dark mode manually, so you want to use the `class` strategy.
By default, the strategy is `media`, based on the operating system preference.

So you need to add this in your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

More details here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually

Comment: `module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {....}
  }`

I'm already using 'class' and as I mentioned I have checked the documentation.